# Starting with black 100x100 jpg and turning some pixels white with a probability

Tags: python, image, numpy, matplotlib

Let's say I have a 100x100 black jpeg. Every pixel has a 1% chance of turning white every iteration, and I execute 30 loops.

If generating it is better, I am thinking maybe some kind of 100x100 array where every value starts black (0) and some turn white (1), and then turning this array into an image printed on the console or saved (for every iteration)

If it is even possible, I would like to further add a chance modifier where some columns have a higher chance than others, based on the height of a circular curve: maximum chance at the centre, and decreasing further out.

How would I go about doing this? If the circle equation part cannot be done, no problem. Just getting a square grid changing is sufficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you going:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.misc import imsave

N = 100

def iterate(img, filename, it_num):
    swaps = np.random.choice((0, 255), size=(N,N))
    img = np.clip(img + swaps, 0, 255)
    imsave(filename + '_it_' + str(it_num) + '.jpg', img)
    if np.all(img):
        return None
    else:
        return img

img = np.zeros((N, N), dtype=np.uint8)
it = 1
while img is not None:
    img = iterate(img, 'output', it)
    it += 1
```

The last image, which is full of 255 should be white, but gets indeed black. I'm not sure why, but i'm also not sure if that's important.

Your circle-equation part is not really formulated in a precise way and i skipped it. It's probably not that hard, using numpy's random-tools.

Comment: Thank you, this is immensely appreciated! Far surpassed what i expected, thank you! Im pretty sure i can figure out the rest, and modify it to my precise problem.